Password visibility is not showing in chrome and firefox
I am currently developing a C# application and aiming to ensure compatibility across all major web browsers. However, I've encountered an issue specifically with the password visibility icon. This icon, which allows users to toggle the visibility of their password input, appears correctly in Microsoft Edge but does not show up in Google Chrome or Mozilla Firefox. This inconsistency in browser behavior is affecting the user experience, and I am seeking a solution to ensure that the password visibility icon is consistently displayed across all browsers.
Below are my login code which I have tried:
image in Edge:

image in chrome & Firefox:



        function validateForm() {
            const username = document.getElementById('username').value;
            const password = document.getElementById('password').value;
            const errorMessage = document.getElementById('error-message');
 
            if (!username && !password) {
                errorMessage.textContent = 'Please enter both username and password.';
                errorMessage.style.display = 'block';
                return false;
            } else if (!username) {
                errorMessage.textContent = 'Please enter your username.';
                errorMessage.style.display = 'block';
                return false;
            } else if (!password) {
                errorMessage.textContent = 'Please enter your password.';
                errorMessage.style.display = 'block';
                return false;
            } else {
                errorMessage.style.display = 'none';
                return true;
            }
        }
        document.getElementById('username').addEventListener('input', function () {
            const errorMessage = document.getElementById('error-message');
            if (errorMessage.style.display === 'block') {
                // Remove error message if there's a change in the username field
                errorMessage.style.display = 'none';
            }
        });
 
        document.getElementById('password').addEventListener('input', function () {
            const errorMessage = document.getElementById('error-message');
            if (errorMessage.style.display === 'block') {
                // Remove error message if there's a change in the password field
                errorMessage.style.display = 'none';
            }
        });
        body, html {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            font-family: Arial, sans-serif; /* Improve font */
        }
 
        .wrapper {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            /*background-color: #f4f4f4; /* Light background color */
        }
 
        .content {
            max-width: 400px;
            width: 100%;
            padding: 20px;
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
            border-radius: 10px;
            box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
            text-align: center;
            background-color: #fff;
        }
 
        .logo img {
            max-width: 100%;
            height: 150px;
            margin-bottom: 20px;
            margin-top: 0;
        }
 
        .form-group {
            margin-bottom: 15px;
            text-align: left;
            display: flex;
            align-items: center; /* Align items vertically within .form-group */
        }
 
            .form-group label {
                flex: 1; /* Take up remaining space */
            }
 
            .form-group input {
                flex: 2;
                margin-left: 10px;
                height: 30px; /* Adjust the height as needed */
                width: 300px; /* Fixed width for input fields */
            }
 
        .btn {
            width: 100%;
            background-color: #53a4fe;
            border-color: #53a4fe;
            border-radius: 5px; /* Add a slight curve to the edges */
            padding: 10px; /* Adjust padding for better appearance */
            color: #fff; /* Button text color */
            cursor: pointer; /* Change cursor to pointer */
        }
 
            .btn:hover {
                background-color: #4290e6;
                border-color: #4290e6;
            }
 
        .error-message {
            color: red;
            margin-top: 10px;
            text-align: center;
        }
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
<title>@ViewData["Title"]</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css"> <!-- Link your external CSS -->
<link rel="icon" href="~/wdfavicon.ico" type="image/x-icon"> <!-- Add this line to set the favicon -->
</head>
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="content">
<h4>Login to Admin Migration Portal</h4>
<div class="logo">
<img src="~/images/WDLogo.png" alt="WD Logo">
</div>
<form class="input-form" method="post" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
<div class="form-group">
<label for="username">Username:</label>
<input type="text" asp-for="Username" class="form-control" id="username" placeholder="Enter your username" aria-describedby="nameHelp">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="password">Password:</label>
<input type="password" asp-for="Password" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your password" id="password">
</div>
<div class="buttons">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
</div>
</form>
<div class="error-message" id="error-message" style="display: none;">
                Please enter both username and password.
</div>
     /*       @if (TempData["UserAuthStatus"] != null)
            {
<div class="error-message">
                    @TempData["UserAuthStatus"]
</div>
            }*/
</div>
</div>
 
    <script src="~/js/site.js"></script> <!-- Link your external JavaScript -->

</body>
</html>




The eye icon on password input is specific to Edge, if you want it for other browsers you will need to code it yourself.

@Arkellys, thank you for letting me know, will create a custom visibility toggle to work with other browsers as well
